# I am not able to import beautifulsoup or requests

Tags: python, installation, beautifulsoup, pip, python-requests

I have switched from Pycharm to using Sublime Text, and importing/installing beautifulsoup4 and requests, (I will probably have the same problem with other modules) seems rather complicated. 
I've tried installing them both by typing the followling in my terminal

```
sudo pip install requests
```

and the same for beautifulsoup4 (I have pip installed).
When I, in terminal, type

```
python
```

and then

```
import requests
```

and

```
from bs4 import beautifulsoup4
```

It says for requests:

```
ImportError: No module named requests
```

and for soup:

```
ImportError: cannot import name beautifulsoup4
```

What am I doing wrong? I haven't even tried doing anything in Sublime Text yet.

Comment: try:
which pip
which python
python --version.
It looks like your pip is pointing to different python installed in your machine

Comment: Okay, now requests work. I installed it using sudo pip3 install requests. But soup still doesn't work

Comment: pip3 install beautifulsoup4

Comment: Now I have uninstalled with pip and pip3 beautifulsoup and installed it again using pip3, still not working

Comment: run: pip list and pip3 list

Comment: Instead of installing packages globally on your machine, it would be a good practice to use virtualenv:
1. mkdir /User/yourname/Documents/Pythonfiles/test
2. cd /User/yourname/Documents/Pythonfiles/test
3. virtualenv env
4. source env/bin/activate
5. pip install packages_names

Comment: Both of them contain requests. pip doesn't have soup. Should I install that?

Comment: Which python are you using?

Comment: Btw I'm on a Mac

Comment: Im using python3

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: I have created the virtual, and installed beautifulsoup and requests, but soup still doesnt work. I test it by typing the import right after "python" in the terminal. I dont understand why creating the virtualenv matters

Comment: It is a good practice.  when you say does not work, what error do you get? 
show come code

Comment: >>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import beautifulsoup4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'beautifulsoup4'

Comment: Whenever I exit terminal and enter again the import request doesn't work and im not in virtualenv. Is that normal?

Comment: once you leave the terminal. you need to activate your env again.
source env/bin/activate

Comment: Now I have tried doing the imports in Sublime text, and here soup works, but requests gets an error. This could not be because of the env?

Comment: It could be in Sublimes configs, make sure it points to env you created.

Comment: https://realpython.com/blog/python/setting-up-sublime-text-3-for-full-stack-python-development/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cannot import name beautifulsoup4
means that you are trying to this:

```
from bs4 import beautifulsoup4
```

instead of:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it!